# how can i store an image in my postgresql database?

Tags: forms

I want to save some data in my module's form like an image.

In fact i want to store an image in my Postgresql database.

Comment: FWIW, this is normally __NOT__ a good idea as serving and caching the image becomes vastly more complicated problems.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [Storage API module](https://drupal.org/project/storage_api).

This allows you to set a field's upload destination to a custom storage class, one of which is database.

I've used this module for this exact purpose and worked well.